# Get the latest records of a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query in postgres using (rails) activerecord, but can't seem to solve it.

A Company has many pages, and I'm trying to get the latest page of all companies.

I tried

```
Page.select('DISTINCT company_id')
```

which gives me 1 page of all companies. But this isn't the latest (created_at ASC)

So I tried

```
Page.select('DISTINCT company_id').order('created_at ASC')
```

which gives an error since created at isn't in the select. But if I add it, I get all records returned.

So I tried

```
Page.group('company_id').select('company_id').order('created_at ASC')
```

But this gives an error, that created_at should be in group by or aggregator function.

adding created_at to the group by, gives unwanted result (multiple pages, of the same company)

Any help?

edit:

I like it to be a scope, I need to chain the scopes later on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) and [`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
Page.order('created_at ASC').pluck(:company_id).uniq
```

You could try this to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
Page.select('max(id) as id, company_id').group(:company_id)
```

I would use `id` to determine the "recentness" of a page instead of `created_at`. The higher the `id` the more recent the page is. You can simply get the highest page `id` per `company_id` with the code above.

Comment: I like to create a scope (so it returns activerecord relation), so I can chain it. Basicly I want for instance Page.unique_for_companies.active or something similar

Comment: OK, I'll update my answer. You have to use `group` and an aggregate function on `created_at` then.

Comment: @Mischa i am not sure about your solution . as it will give the unique company_ids from the pages table. it is not going to provide the latest created pages for each comapny

Comment: I'm getting: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Page id: nil, company_id: 5>, #<Page id: nil, company_id: 12>]>

Which is about right, but without the id, I still can't do anything with it. Probally chaining certain scopes would not work, because lack of the id. Is it possible to get the whole AR object?

Comment: Sorry, it does seem to be possible: just add `id` to your `select`.

Comment: Which causes the following error: column "pages.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Adding id to the group, return all the objects :(

Comment: I re-read your question and now I think I understand what you're trying to. Instead of `created_at`, I recommend using `id` to determine the "recentness" of a page. See updated answer.

Answer (score -4):

Order by created_at (descending) and limit 1.